# change curl cmd to python

Tags: python, json, curl

I am a beginner. I am trying to change a curl cmd to an actually Post request in my python code.
Each time, I am getting either a 404 or 400 errors. I am a bit lost. Thanks.

Curl request : `(echo -n '{"data": "'; base64 test-1.pdf; echo '", "extension": ".pdf"}') | curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @- http://localhost:5000`

My python code:

```
import json
import requests
url ='http://localhost:5000/POST'
newHeaders = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.post(url, json={"data": "'; base64 test-1.pdf; echo '", "extension": ".pdf"},headers=newHeaders)
print("Status code: ", response.status_code)
response_Json = response.json()
print("Printing Post JSON data")
print(response_Json['data'])
print("Content-Type is ", response_Json['headers']['Content-Type'])
```

Comment: I think you just want `url ='http://localhost:5000'` ... not that `/POST` bit

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, I am still getting an error, but this time is 500. On the server, the error is more explicit: `File "/home/myuser/backend/main.py", line 23, in predict
    fp.write(base64.b64decode(data))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/base64.py", line 87, in b64decode
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding`

Comment: @JulieM 500 is a server-side error.

Comment: Does your curl command work successfully?

Comment: the curl is successful

Comment: Looking at this more carefully: the curl version is running the `base64` program. Your python script is not going to do that unless you use `subprocess` or do the equivalent conversion in python itself.

Comment: Thank, do you have an example that I could easily use? I am really a fresh beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your URL is wrong and should not have the `/POST` at the end, but in addition to that, you need to actually base64-encode the `test-1.pdf` (this is what the shell command that runs `curl` is doing).

You could use this (combined with the code in the question) to put the correct value into the parameters dictionary.

```
import base64

#...
b64 = base64.b64encode(open("test-1.pdf", "rb").read()).decode()
response = requests.post(url,
                         json={"data": b64,
                               "extension": ".pdf"},
                         headers=newHeaders)
```

Comment: Hi Alaniwi, thank a lot for the quick and detailed reply, I have now another error : `TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable`

Comment: @JulieM Edited - please give this a try. I've inserted a `decode` to turn the bytes into a string. Unfortunately I can't test it as it is relying on whatever server you are running on localhost.

Comment: I tried and I have this error : `File "<ipython-input-86-7f2d14f02b90>", line 6
    responses = requests.post(url,
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax` 
thank again

Comment: @JulieM Sorry, a stray close parentheses - I'll remove it. (Now done.)

Comment: I added an extra bracket after encode()) but i have a new error  :`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 11: invalid continuation byte`

Comment: @JulieM I've rather messed up on these parentheses during recent editing a couple of times. Now hopefully corrected but can I check that what you have now is the latest version? The base64 encoding should produce plain ASCII so invalid bytes during decoding to a string shouldn't arise.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is indeed working ! you are great :)